# Pass AntiForgeryToken from controller to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is there a way to pass the AntiForgeryToken from controller to controller?

PAController

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Cancel()
    {
        var result = MvcApplication.API.CancelPaymentPlan(LoginToken);
        if (result.ResultID == 0)
        {
            AccountDetails = null;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
            return PartialView("_GeneralErrorPartialView", result);
        
    }
```

HomeController

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if the same token to be passed? because your question is unclear knowing what [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] does and its purpose.

Comment: yes, My scenario is redirect to the same action ("Index") of Home controller from Login and PAController. Can i use the same token?

Comment: Nope, because you have to use antiforgery in a submit form, and each submit form will take you to different controllers in your case.